# Only display post content in search results

Tags: search

How can I just show the post content in a search result? Currently, the search results displays the post title, author and date above the page content.

Here is how it looks now: http://sikkervaccination.dk/?s=thailand

Comment: What do you want to happen if the search returns more than one result?

Comment: Impossible to tell when we don't know A) your theme template code and B) if there's plugins influencing the search results are involved. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some themes like Twenty Fourteen include a template tag included in the content.php file for entry meta which includes the author and date:

Example:

```
twentyfourteen_posted_on();
```

The content.php file also includes [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) tag so you need to remove that if you don't want the entry titles displaying on your search result pages.

The search.php file includes this tag which includes the content.php

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

To display content only on the search results pages, you would need to create your own custom search.php file.

To do this using the Twenty Fourteen theme for example, copy over the search.php file to a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and modify the code there.

You could then copy over the content.php file from your parent theme to your child theme, rename it to something like customsearch.php and change the template template in your child themes search.php file to:

```
get_template_part( 'customsearch' );
```

Then you simply modify your customsearch.php file in your child theme and your code is saved from any parent theme updates.

[Source & Examples](http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/twenty-fourteen-theme-custom-search-results-page/)

Answer (score 0):

You can usually modify the display of your search results by editing a loop in `search.php` file in your theme folder. It depends on your theme, though. Some themes may have this code located in another file, like `loop.php`, `loop-search.php` or `loop-posts.php` to give you some examples, but you should start by looking at the `search.php` file.

Comment: I have installed the plugin "Relevanssi" and limited the indexed pages by excluding all the unwanted pages by page-id. Should the search return more than one result the content would be stacked on top of each other in order of relevance (determined by the plugin parameters). 

I could not find any relevant code in any of those files though.

Here is a url by the way: http://sikkervaccination.dk/?s=thailand

Comment: What kind of code should i look for in those files? I might be looking for the wrong thing?

Comment: [This page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) may give you an idea of where the search page is located. Different themes handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

In your post loop in search.php, add this code

```
the_content(); // use this line or use below one
echo get_the_content($post->ID);
```